# Excel - formula appears instead of results

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel file that in some cells shows me the formula and in other cells shows the results.

How can I fix it? I only want see the results in all cells.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  As you will see, your question belongs on a different site (SuperUser).  Sorry for the downvotes, and may all your spreadsheets be blessed.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you have toggled showing the formula instead of the result.  Select the cells you want to change and press `Ctrl + tilde` (which looks like ` and is found on the top left of your keyboard right under the Esc key. This will toggle showing the formula or result.

If that is not a solution try this.
Check if the cells which display formula instead of result are formatted as text. If so then change the cell format to General.

Right click on the cell(s) > Format cells > Select General